# stop/start setInterval function with a delta time in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible that pause setInterval function without clearInterval and setInterval again? I want to pause it a delta time without removing it.

Comment: nope, its not possible.

Comment: Nope. Instead, create some flag variable and put `if (thatFlag) { return; }` at the beginning of the callback function (which is the first parameter of setInterval).